# WordPress - Different CSS for Dropdown Menu

Tags: wordpress

On my WordPress website I have used wp_nav_menu to create the navigation bar. Because of this I have limited control over the HTML, for one of the navigation links I have started styling it to be a dropdown. However, the CSS for the rest of the navigation bar is interfering with this, how can I modify the HTML so that I can separate the two?

HTML -

```
<nav class="site-nav">
    <div class="menu-primary-menu-links-container"><ul id="menu-primary-menu-links" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-36" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-36"><a href="http://localhost/testsite/contact/">Contact</a></li>
         <li id="menu-item-37" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-37"><a href="http://localhost/testsite/tuition/">Tuition</a></li>
         <li id="menu-item-38" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-28 current_page_item current_page_parent menu-item-38"><a href="http://localhost/testsite/blog/">Blog</a></li>
         <li id="menu-item-107" class="test menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-107"><a href="http://localhost/testsite/shop/">Gallery</a>
               <ul class="sub-menu">
                     <li id="menu-item-119" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-119"><a href="http://localhost/testsite/product-category/animals/">Animals</a></li>
                     <li id="menu-item-120" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-120"><a href="http://localhost/testsite/product-category/contemporary-space-images/">Contemporary Space Images</a></li>
               </ul>
         </li>
         <li id="menu-item-42" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home menu-item-42"><a href="http://localhost/testsite/">Home</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Try with Walker Class -- more info here (https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/understanding-the-walker-class--wp-25401)

Comment: You may have to add Custom Attributes in your Nav Menu. You can do this by without creating Nav Walker Class. 

I had similar issue like this before. You can take a reference of this blog.

http://prabinparajuli.com.np/add-custom-attributes-wordpress-nav-item/

Comment: Thank you Prabin, that was extremely helpful!